# Home directory for the www-data user?

Tags: permissions, apache2

As I understand the **www-data** user is the user that owns the apache service.

From the `/etc/passwd` file I have:

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

So the home dir for **www-data** is: **/var/www** but if I check the permissions for that folder I get:

```
/var/www $ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mar 20 19:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Mar 20 19:42 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 20 19:42 html/
```

So it appears that **root** owns that folder. Why is it not the **www-data** user that owns the **/var/www** directory (its home directory)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reason for the webserver to able to write to that directory by default. The administrator should decide which directories and files the webserver should be able to modify, and grant permissions on those accordingly. Having `/var/www` be owned by root is a safe and secure default.

Comment: It could lead to problems if you want to upload files e.g. via ftp directly to the folder using a different user (better not root ;) ).

Comment: @Lord_PedantenStein then you should modify the permissions accordingly. You don't have a FTP server running by default, do you?

Comment: Nah everything OK back here. ;) - but if someone wants to upload his or her files to that directory something like http://askubuntu.com/questions/68007/configuring-permissions-for-ftp-and-apache should be done. regards